# How to change a grammar so that it can be unambiguous?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

The original grammar is
$$ S \to SaS \mid SbS \mid ScS \mid d $$
My answer is
$$ S \to daS \mid dbS \mid dcS \mid d $$
Is that correct?

Comment: We don't typically check exercises. We can help if you have any specific doubts.

Comment: Yeah cuz i got the reference giving an answer as follows: S -> SaD | D D->DbE | E E -> EcF | F F->d im not sure cuz my answer is really simple so that i'm afraid there's something wrong